# Federated Learning and Continual Learning: Non-IID Learning

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, definition, continual-learning

I have some exposure to federated learning and continual learning which are non-iid learning instances [[1]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9439935) and [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.11028) I was wondering can we state the following:

> Federated learning is when the dataset is distributed in a non-iid
> manner over space (different edge-devices at different geographical
> locations). Meanwhile, continual/incremental learning is when the
> dataset is distributed in a non-iid manner over time (each time a
> class is seen). Then, we could state that federated learning and
> continual learning are subclasses of non-iid learning.

Do you agree with this conclusion? What are the implications in your opinion?

Comment: I don't think there is a universal/accepted classification. There are a lot of overlaps among the concepts: Federated learning implies privacy and distributed learning and can be practiced in many ways but sequential learning is not a prerequisite